# Windows 10 looses internet connection after 90 minutes

Tags: windows

I have a problem with Windows 10 and I am kinda clueless on why and how I should fix it.

I have a work laptop that was upgraded to windows 10 last month. Ever since I got it I have been having problems with my Internet connection. About every one or 2 hours I stop being able to access the internet. I try and run the Windows diagnostic tool but there are of no help. Only restarting the computer helps, which is a major pain. 
I have installed Wireshark to monitor my connections but unfortunately I am not really savvy with it. I can however see that there are quite a few broadcasts being made (they make 90% of all connections being made) but I cannot see from where they come. 
I have tried disabling all energy saving options, updating the drivers for the network adapter, reinstalling the antivirus and even a hardware test. Nothing helped. My next step would be to reinstall Windows but I only want to do that as a last resort. 
Any ideas what I could do next?

Comment: do a `sfc /scannnow` using command prompt and let it complete

Comment: Thank you for the reply? Why should I run this command?

Comment: it will scan the windows system files in the PC and replace with fresh ones.

[reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system)

Comment: Thank you. I let it run, it did find and repaired some files. I don´t know exactly which ones (the log was kinda long). However, it unfortunately did not change anything. I still cannot access any websites after using my pc for a while.

Comment: okay i think the inbuild image is not capable of recovering the files. try use this one   but you have to have internet access about 20 minuits it will download the windows installation file and reparir it `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`

Comment: I have had to reinstall windows 10 because I needed the computer for work. Unfortunately the problem remains. Maybe is it a hardware problem. I am looking into it and will update when I know more. Thank you for your help

Comment: Cheers. check the neetwork card drivers if you can.

Answer (score -1):

So, I actually fixed my problem. I didn´t really figure out exactly why it happened but I found a work around. 
In Windows 10, I opened the Event log to see if there was an error being logged. Thankfully I have been documenting when I lost connection so this was easy to find. I saw that everytime I lost connection, Event 4231 was being logged. I googled the Id and found a solution on [this](https://deploymentresearch.com/Research/Post/532/Fix-for-Windows-10-exhausted-pool-of-TCP-IP-ports) website. 
I followed the instructions there and had no more problems ever since.